# Is there an up to date Xamarin component for BLE? The website links to a 404 page

Tags: xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to implempent cross-platform bluetooth functionality into my Xamarin application for IOS and Android, but the links on the Xamarin website are deprecated and/or missing from the site entirely.

https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/mobile/BluetoothLEExplorer/

This link is where the documentation sends me, and the page states that the code is deprecated and links to something else called Monkey Robotics, however that component is no longer available in the component store. Am I missing something here?

Comment: The one I'm using (MvvmCross variant) is this one: https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le

Comment: I did see that a bit ago. Is that the best option we have? I was hoping to find something with a bit better documentation as I've never implimented bluetooth before. I'm kind of at a loss for how to use that in alignment with my webview instead of xamarin forms.

Comment: There is a nuget (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Monkey.Robotics/) but personally I would just pull the Mobile Stack source portion into your solution so you can work with it directly (https://github.com/xamarin/Monkey.Robotics)